# How can I make a GUI test focus on and the same time continue working with my PC?

Tags: automated-tests

I understand that Two users cannot work on the same machine at the same time, and Test Compleate interacts with GUI in the way a user would do.But probably there is some way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Test Complete so I can't say anything about workarounds specific to this product (that may well exist!), but one option is always to set up Virtual Machines and run the tests in there. Some of the most popular virtual machines (they all have free editions) are [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com) and [Microsoft Virtual P](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/)C.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.
Ok we working with VMware,but I just beginner programmer and I dont understand how it help me to solve my problem.I understand from people that work in QA that if they move mouse when test running,test failed. If I run the test on virtual mashine does it mean that I can continue working on my PC and my test will run at the same time and not failed?
How I need to set up it? There is some special configuration?

Comment: @Sigal whatever you do on the virtual machine will not affect your working on your "real" machine, so yes, you can continue working and the tests running in the VM will not fail. It's like a separate computer in a computer. You need a separate operating system (and a license if you have a commercial OS like Windows!), and install the virtual machine like you would install a new computer. For detail questions on how to set up a virtual machine, head over to superuser.com where there are many questions dealing with the issues. Windows 7 professional already has a VM built in.

Comment: Pekka's VM solution is a good one. Another option is to run the tests on a separate machine. Although running the tests in a VM on your own PC will work, running a VM will slow your PC down. That's why I will typically run my automated tests on a separate machine directly or in a VM on a separate machine.

Answer (score 0):

try UI Automation (MS UIAutomation library or UiAutomation PowerShell module, for example), it frequently pulls the AUT to the foreground. Moreover, it has the abiblity to set the focus (AutomationElement.SetFocus(), Set-UIAFocus).